# requireNativeComponent: 'BVLinearGradient' was not found in the UIManager

Tags: react-native

I'm using react native expo managed project. But i cannot use react-native-linear-gradient. It gives me error: 'BVLinearGradient' was not found in the UIManager. Here is my code:

[Here is my example code screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzvWv.png)

Please, help me.

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably your podfiles and/or Frameworks aren't installed properly.

Try running this in your project root:

```
$ npx react-native link react-native-linear-gradient
$ npx pod-install
```

Then try recompiling your project.